# Visual studio proffesional 2017 - Add existing website to solution doesn't responding

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, vs-web-site-project

I own windows 10, when im trying to add an existing website to solution, nothing happens.

Iv'e Been trying to right click on solution -> Add -> Existing website . .
and File -> Add -> Existing website . .

I tried to look up on the net for answers but only found other people with the same problem, no answers.